# librrd link problem

Tags: c, gcc

i use rrd (graphic programming ) under rrdtool, i have installed; and i rund gcc
gcc -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lrrd -o myprog test.c

myprog is execute file
and test.c ist testprogram who i use  function rrd_create from libary but gcc put out error like this:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrrd
why!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that the linker cannot locate librrd.a or librrd.so* in /usr/lib/ or /usr/local/lib. You should make sure that you have librrd installed, and not just some other binary rrd package.

Comment: Is it possible that this file is a broken symlink?

Comment: Also ensure `librrd-dev` is installed